# BB10 Simulator Camera Support

Tags: apache-flex, air, blackberry-simulator

Is the Camera supported on the BB10 Simulator?

I need to port an existing Flex app and don't have a physical device, but the bundled camera app does nothing when clicked and initiating a Camera object in AIR doesn't show anything.

I have assigned both the built in and USB cameras connected to my MBP to the Fusion VM, but don't see any change.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your laptop's camera but (unfortunately) only with the 10.2 emulator, 10.1 does not seem to be supported, take a look at this post: http://devblog.blackberry.com/2013/08/10-2-gold-simulator/. You can run 10.1 apps in there and from what I've read there haven't been any significant AIR-related changes so it might be *good enough* for your case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so man I downloaded a sample app called photobomber from developers.blackberry.com and I'm running it on WMware, it can't access my laptops camera. There's gotta be a way though we need to change some kinda setting for the cam on your computer and i think import an API? I'm not sure